# Security and distro list naming convention in AAD

Tags: active-directory, azure, standards

Most naming convention standards for Active Directory I have come across so far have security groups starting with an underscore to allow the equivalent distribution list to be user-friendly.

I am now writing a naming convention for Azure AD implementation and was wondering whether others are still using a this conventions (for example to distinguish between AAD and 365 groups)?

Comment: Really? Companies I have worked at have used either prefix for group names, or used g.

Comment: Interesting! I’ve seen GS and LS in the past (global security and local security) in defence but never simply a ‘g’